# Synthesized iVar not accessible from subclass

Tags: objective-c, properties, instance-variables, access-control

I have the following code which gives the compiler error `"Instance Variable '_someBool' is prive"`.

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@property (assign) BOOL someBool;
@end
@implementation Foo
@end

@interface Bar: Foo
@end
@implementation Bar
- (BOOL)someBool {
    // subclass specific getter logic
    return _someBool;
}
@end
```

Why can't I access the storage of the property that was inherited?  And what would be the proper way to override this getter?

Answer (score 1):

A getter is just a method, if you wish to override a method and call its original implementation you use `super`:

```
- (BOOL)someBool
{
   // subclass specific getter logic
   return [super someBool];
}
```

> Why can't I access the storage of the property that was inherited?

It is private. If you *really* want to access the storage from a subclass then specify your own storage by declaring an `@protected` instance variable and using `@synthesise property=variable`. Using `super` is probably better.

Comment: in my case the super class is an "abstract interface" that throws assertions in all method implementations.  can't change that.  went with overriding setter/getter in subclass and adding an iVar there.  property still defined in super.

Comment: @AlexBollbach - If the property getter and setter have both been defined in the "abstract" superclass to throw assertions then there won't be any automatically allocated backing variable, so you're not "losing" space to it. Adding your own iVar as you've done is the way to go.

Comment: only the getters have been overrode in the super.